# Reset positions drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, reset

could someone help me, how to reset dragged items to the default positions (same as after page load)??
 For example after click on button..
There is a link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dj8q2qmb/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".card").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    cursor: "move",
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: "invalid",
  });

  $(".launchPad").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".card",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
    }
  });

  $(".stackDrop").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".card",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `clone()` list before changes made
and re-listen to dragging if reset button clicked

Test on https://jsfiddle.net/dj8q2qmb/3/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    //clone list
    var launchPad = $(".launchPad").clone();
   //reset button
    $("[name='reset']").click(function(){
    //empty bottom div
    $("#dropZone .stackDrop").empty();
    //get cloned content
    $(".launchPad").html(launchPad.html());
    //re-listen to dragging  
    listenToDragable();
    });

    //listen to dragging
    listenToDragable();

    function listenToDragable(){
      $(".card").draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        cursor: "move",
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: "invalid",
      });

      $(".launchPad").droppable({
        tolerance: "intersect",
        accept: ".card",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
        }
      });

      $(".stackDrop").droppable({
        tolerance: "intersect",
        accept: ".card",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
        }
      });
    }
    });
```